# Python rfecv select less than recommended features

Tags: python, feature-selection

I have this example code that comes from [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_rfe_with_cross_validation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-feature-selection-plot-rfe-with-cross-validation-py). Optimal number of features recommended by [rfecv](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html) is 3. But if want to build the model with only 1 or 2 features, how should I select those features?

```
"""
===================================================
Recursive feature elimination with cross-validation
===================================================

A Recursive Feature Elimination (RFE) example with automatic tuning of the
number of features selected with cross-validation.

"""

# %%
# Data generation
# ---------------
#
# We build a classification task using 3 informative features. The introduction
# of 2 additional redundant (i.e. correlated) features has the effect that the
# selected features vary depending on the cross-validation fold. The remaining
# features are non-informative as they are drawn at random.

from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(
    n_samples=500,
    n_features=15,
    n_informative=3,
    n_redundant=2,
    n_repeated=0,
    n_classes=8,
    n_clusters_per_class=1,
    class_sep=0.8,
    random_state=0,
)

# %%
# Model training and selection
# ----------------------------
#
# We create the RFE object and compute the cross-validated scores. The scoring
# strategy "accuracy" optimizes the proportion of correctly classified samples.

from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

min_features_to_select = 1  # Minimum number of features to consider
clf = LogisticRegression()
cv = StratifiedKFold(5)

rfecv = RFECV(
    estimator=clf,
    step=1,
    cv=cv,
    scoring="accuracy",
    min_features_to_select=min_features_to_select,
    n_jobs=2,
)
rfecv.fit(X, y)

print(f"Optimal number of features: {rfecv.n_features_}")

# %%
# In the present case, the model with 3 features (which corresponds to the true
# generative model) is found to be the most optimal.
#
# Plot number of features VS. cross-validation scores
# ---------------------------------------------------

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_scores = len(rfecv.cv_results_["mean_test_score"])
plt.figure()
plt.xlabel("Number of features selected")
plt.ylabel("Mean test accuracy")
plt.errorbar(
    range(min_features_to_select, n_scores + min_features_to_select),
    rfecv.cv_results_["mean_test_score"],
    yerr=rfecv.cv_results_["std_test_score"],
)
plt.title("Recursive Feature Elimination \nwith correlated features")
plt.show()

# %%
# From the plot above one can further notice a plateau of equivalent scores
# (similar mean value and overlapping errorbars) for 3 to 5 selected features.
# This is the result of introducing correlated features. Indeed, the optimal
# model selected by the RFE can lie within this range, depending on the
# cross-validation technique. The test accuracy decreases above 5 selected
# features, this is, keeping non-informative features leads to over-fitting and
# is therefore detrimental for the statistical performance of the models.
```